# sqlite INNER JOIN only if data

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, restriction

Example with tables :

Promotion(idPromo, nameUser)

Company(idCompany, nameCompany)

PromoCompany(idPromo, idCompany)

I try to get with only one query, all promotions who have a company (idCompany = 1 for example) OR who have 0 company.

To describe :
PromoCompany is a restriction table... if data exist for a promotion, promotion is valable for only this companies, if no data, promotion valable for all companies.

Example :

```
Promo[{
    idPromo:1
    namePromo:"promo test"
    },
    {
    idPromo:2
    namePromo:"promo test 2"
    }]
Company[{
    idCompany:10
    nameCompany:"CompanyPloof"
},{
    idCompany:12
    nameCompany:"CompanyPaf"
}
]
PromoCompany[{
    idPromo:1
    idCompany:10
},{
    idPromo:1
    idCompany:12
}
    ]
```

If my company is CompanyPloof, promos are idPromo 1 et 2

If my company is CompanyPaf, promos are idPromo 2 (because not restricted)

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also, your attempt at a query would also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmm . . . this sounds like two conditions:

```
select p.*
from promotions p
where exists (select 1 from promocompany pc where pc.idpromo = p.idpromo and p.idcompany = 1) or
      not exists (select 1 from promocompany pc where pc.idpromo = p.idpromo);
```

I would suggest a small change to your data model.  Add a flag in `promotions` that says whether the promotion is available for all companies or if it is restricted.  Having to search through a table is a little awkward -- and potentially confusing.  Adding one row to the table could invalidate a promotion for everyone else.

Comment: Thank you, i'll try. I can't change data model, this is not my development